# Hex Strings inside of Oracle .dmp file. What's that about?

Tags: oracle

I need to restore a customer's DB, and as I was scrolling through the SHOW file and I noticed several very large areas of strings like:

```
:2 36 41 1 1a 2f :2 1a 3a :2 1a.
```

The rest is garden variety SQL statements, so I was wondering if anyone can tell me what type of info is being given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much detail here....Oracle edition?  Version?

But, two guesses, off the top of my head would be wrapped PL/SQL code, or possibly blob data, though I don't know how Oracle would encode BLOB data in an export .dmp file.

The real problem is that the .dmp file format is not documented, so, you can never be sure of what you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not positive about the version since it comes from an outside client, but it starts with: Export file created by EXPORT:V10.02.01 via direct path. I forgot about the "secrecy" of the .dmp file format.